# Rplidar A2 is not running on the humble version

Tags: ros-humble, rplidar, 2dlidar

I'm using Rplidar A2.
I'm referring to the video in the link below.

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJZXRncGaGM)

If you run a command like this

```
ros2 run rplidar_ros rplidar_composition --ros-args -p serial_port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 -p frame_id:=lidar_link -p angle_compensate:=true -p scan_mode:=Standard
```

This kind of error will occur.

```
[INFO] [1704297293.989817372] [rplidar_node]: RPLidar running on ROS2 package 
rplidar_ros. RPLIDAR SDK Version:2.0.0
[ERROR] [1704297298.047404306] [rplidar_node]: Error, operation time out. 
SL_RESULT_OPERATION_TIMEOUT! 
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 255
```

I'm sure I used the foxy version, I didn't have this problem, so how should I solve it?
There is currently nothing connected to the USB other than lidar.
It's 256000 on lidar as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with Rplidar A1 but was able to fix with https://github.com/babakhani/rplidar_ros2